# UIBezierPath different colors

Tags: xcode, uibezierpath

I was able to draw with UIBezierPath in my app. Now I added a UIColor variable so the user, pushing a button, can select a different color. When the user change the color and he start drawing with the new color, all the paths already drawn have the new color.

How can I tell the object to not change the color of the already drawn paths?

Here is my code. Any example of code is much appreciated! :)

(I have my UIColor variable storaged in the appDelegate and I am calling the refresh method from another viewControlle.

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    myPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    myPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    myPath.miterLimit = 0;
    myPath.lineWidth = 5;

    brushPattern = app.currentColor;

}
   return self;
}
-(void)refresh {
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    brushPattern = app.currentColor;
}



- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     [brushPattern setStroke];
     for (UIBezierPath *_path in pathArray)
     [_path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   myPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
   myPath.lineWidth = 5;

    UITouch *mytouch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [myPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
    [pathArray addObject:myPath];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     UITouch *mytouch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
     [myPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];
     [self setNeedsDisplay];
 }

 -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 }
```

Comment: Do you have got any solution ? If you have already then post in answer, So it will be helpful to others..

Comment: No, sorry. I needed to change system...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found one demo code for that..

Please check this if it will be helpful to you..

[Smooth Line](https://github.com/yusenhan/Smooth-Line-View) link